# How can I code a monitor in C?

Tags: c, unix, semaphore

I need to do some process synchronization in C. I want to use a monitor, and I have read a lot about them. However I have been unable to find out how to implement one in C. I have seen them done in Java and other languages like C++, but I am unable to find examples in C.

I have looked through K&R and there is no example in there. I skimmed through Unix Systems Programming, Communication, Concurrency and Threads, but was unable to find a monitor implementation in there.

This brings me here. Where and how do I define a monitor? How do I implement it within the rest of the code?

/* I am coding in a *nix environment */

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this recently for a project, the concept I implemented was to have one thread start all of the others and then use semaphores and mutexes to control the inter process sync issues while dealing with shared memory.

The concept of a monitor, in the context of the monitor design pattern, is a construct that is basically there to hide mutual exclusion. This concept is expressed in C++ Boost but it doesn't exist in core C++ or C. The way you handle this type of job in C is with good old fashioned mutexes (binary semaphores) and semaphores. You can read more about this [here](http://108leaves.com/dailyc++/?p=4).

Below is a basic way to initialize a semaphore and mutex, you may need to do more research of your own, but [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node32.html) is a link to get you started.

```
pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
sem_t mySemaphore;
int status;
    status = pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL);
    if(status != 0)
        exit_with_error("There was an Error Initalizing the Mutex\n");
    status = sem_init(&mySemaphore, 0, 0);
    if(status != 0)
        printf("There was an Error Initalizing the Semaphore\n");
```

Comment: This implementation is via a function? I have seen some minor code like: monitor network{/*code and conditions in here*/}. Was that pseudo code or is there keyword/data struct for monitors too?

Comment: I've knocked out that monitor function I had and replaced it with a more direct answer. If you'd like that code back just let me know, I just re-read your question and saw that it wasn't quite what you were asking. In your above comment that code that your referring to is pseudo code, to the best of my knowledge that construct doesn't exist in C.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try to implement mine via a function with semaphores in main and try to use it to monitor various threads. I need to read more on the topic, it's quite complex.

Comment: I agree, it is very complex! Many a headache and seg_fault has been hit working out these sorts of problems, that link I posted above helped me a lot. If you have any further questions just post it up.

Answer (score 3):

The above code to init the semaphore and mutex is great. Here is an example of how to use it in a program that could have errors when multi-threaded.

```
struct account{
        int balance;
        int finished;
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
        pthread_cond_t deposit; 
};

static void init_account(struct account *act)
{
        act->balance = 0;
        act->finished = 0;
        pthread_mutex_init(&act->mutex,NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&act->deposit,NULL);
}

static void deposit(struct account *act, int amount)
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&act->mutex);
        fprintf(stderr, "Deposit:%d\n",amount);
        act->balance += amount;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&act->deposit);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&act->mutex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from my operating systems book to solve the "Dining Philosophers" problem. Monitors are better for synchronization than semaphores when processes or threads need to access multiple resources. The book is "Operating Systems: Internals and Design Principles, Seventh Edition, by William Stallings" Ch.6.6.

I know this is a super old question but I hope it helps someone out there :)

```
monitor dining_controller {
    cond ForkReady[3];//clients queue here
    boolean fork[3]={true};//availability of each fork
  
    void get_forks(int pid) { //pid = client id number
        int left = pid;
        int right = (pid++) % 3;
        //grant left fork
        if (!fork[left]){ //if that fork isn't available
            cwait(ForkReady[left]);//queue so others can enter monitor
        }
        fork[left] = false;// make fork unavailable when you get it
        //grant right fork;
        if (!fork[right]){ // if that fork isn't available
            cwait(ForkReady[right]);//queue so others can enter monitor
        }
        fork[right] = false; // make fork unavailable when you get it
    }
    void release_forks(int pid){
        int left = pid;
        int right = (pid++) % 3;
        // release left fork
        if (empty(ForkReady[left])){ // no one is waiting for that fork
            fork[left] = true; //make fork available 
        }
        else{
            csignal(ForkReady[left]);//awaken process in queue
        }
        //release right fork
        if (empty(ForkReady[right])){ //no one is waiting for that fork
            fork[right] = true; //make fork available
        }
        else {
            csignal(ForkReady[right]);//awaken process in queue
        }
    }
}
void philosopher [k=0 to 2]{ //three philosopher clients
    while (true) {
        <think>;
        get_forks(k);//request to enter monitor
        <eat spaghetti>;
        release_forks(k);//request to enter monitor
    }
}
```